# Spring Cloud Gateway and external service

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on an api-gateway and evaluating solutions. Spring cloud gate seems to be a good option. But for my case, it is required to have a custom filter that calls an external service (another spring micro-service may be) and fetch a decision and then filter will act based on that. Is it feasible to have such external communication (generally a grpc service) in a filter for Spring Cloud Gateway?
Any reference if this is possible is highly appreciated!

Comment: Spring gateway documentation has rich examples how to do filters: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/